Weird-looking Dirac constant in LaTeX
I need to use Dirac constant. I use package amssymb and I compile my LaTeX in pdflatex with option '-shell-escape'. I used command  \hslash and \hbar, but they look weird. Here you can see what should I get:

and what I get in reality:

That slash is thicker and lower, I don't like it. Does anyone know, what is happening here and how to fix that?

Voting to move to tex.stackexchange.com, but meanwhile you might want to add a minimal reproducible example.

If I add enough code to compile the fragment, I get https://i.sstatic.net/pB9Wq5ef.png Please add a compilable [mre]

I am using template from internet, I can just send here all packages it uses, if that could help (?).
But even when I delete all text and left only that hbar, it looked weird. So probably there is a problem with template settings, right? Some stupid package is ruining it?

@Lilla_mu sure it is some package or setting related with the font family or style. Please add your code or even just the preamble! :)
